# Azure function app python v2 model - unclosed aiohttp session

Tags: azure-functions, python-asyncio, aiohttp, azure-python-sdk

I am writing an Azure Function App using Python (v2 programming model) that calls an API multiple times to get some data and write the responses to a blob storage. Those operations happen asyncronously, and I am using `aiohttp` to make the API calls. This is the code of my function app:

```py
import azure.functions as func
from azure.storage.blob.aio import BlobServiceClient
import asyncio
import aiohttp
import datetime
import logging
import requests
import json
import sys
import os
import ssl
import certifi

_KV_SECRET_OUTPUT_BLOB_CONNECTION_STRING = os.environ["KV_SECRET_OUTPUT_BLOB_CONNECTION_STRING"]
_KV_SECRET_API_KEY = os.environ["KV_SECRET_API_KEY"]
CRON_SCHEDULE = os.environ["CRON_SCHEDULE"]
STORAGE_CONTAINER_NAME = os.environ["STORAGE_CONTAINER_NAME"]



def timestamp_utc():
    return datetime.datetime.now(datetime.timezone.utc)

def timestamp_for_logs():
    return timestamp_utc().isoformat()

def timestamp_for_blob_path():
    return timestamp_utc().strftime("%Y/%m/%d/T/%H/%M/%S_%Z")


async def makeAPIcall(api_endpoint, session, request_params):
    logging.info(f'attempting to make an API call... with request_params: {request_params}')
    try:
        async with session.get(api_endpoint, params = request_params) as response:
            response.raise_for_status()
            response_content = await response.read()
            logging.info("Response from the API call: "+str(response_content))
            return response_content
                
    except Exception as e:
        logging.error(f'Error calling API:')
        logging.error(str(sys.exc_info()))
        return None


async def writeResponseToBlob(data, container_name, blob_name, connection_string):
    logging.info(f'attempting to write to blob with container name: {container_name} and blob name: {blob_name}')
    try:
        # Create the BlobServiceClient object using the connection string
        blob_service_client =  BlobServiceClient.from_connection_string(connection_string)

        # Get a ContainerClient object for the specified container
        container_client = blob_service_client.get_container_client(container_name)

        # Create a blob in the container with the specified name
        blob_client = container_client.get_blob_client(blob_name)

        # Write the API response to the blob
        await blob_client.upload_blob(data, overwrite=True)

    except:
        logging.error("ERROR during blob upload : "+str(sys.exc_info()))
        sys.exit(1)


async def chain(base_url, satellite_id, request_params, context, container_name, session) -> None:
    # part A of the chain
    api_endpoint = f"{base_url}/{satellite_id}"
    response_content = await makeAPIcall(api_endpoint, session, request_params=request_params)
    
    # part B of the chain
    output_blob_name = timestamp_for_blob_path()+'_SatID_'+str(satellite_id)+'_InvocID_'+context.invocation_id+'.json'
    
    await writeResponseToBlob(data=response_content, 
                              container_name=container_name, 
                              blob_name=output_blob_name, 
                              connection_string=_KV_SECRET_OUTPUT_BLOB_CONNECTION_STRING)
    
    logging.info(f"Finished entire chain for SatID {satellite_id}")


async def main(args, session):

    base_url = args["base_url"]
    satellite_ids =  args["satellite_ids"]
    request_params =  args["request_params"]
    context = args["context"]
    container_name = args["container_name"]
    
    # version A
    # await asyncio.gather(*(chain(base_url, satellite_id, request_params, context, container_name, session) for satellite_id in satellite_ids))

    # version B
    for satellite_id in satellite_ids:
        await chain(base_url, satellite_id, request_params, context, container_name, session)



#===============
# CORE FUNCTION:
#===============

app = func.FunctionApp()
@app.function_name(name="sendReqToApiWriteToBlobTimeTrigger")
@app.schedule(schedule=CRON_SCHEDULE, arg_name="mytimer", run_on_startup=False, use_monitor=True)

async def eventHandler(mytimer: func.TimerRequest, context: func.Context) -> None:
    
    logging.info('ctx_func_name:\t'+context.function_name),
    logging.info('ctx_func_dir:\t'+context.function_directory),
    logging.info('ctx_invocation_id:\t'+context.invocation_id),

    logging.info("Cron schedule UTC:\t"+CRON_SCHEDULE)

    # satellite_ids = [25544, 25544]
    satellite_ids = ["Amsterdam", "London"]
    # base_url = f"https://api.wheretheiss.at/v1/satellites"
    base_url = f"https://worldtimeapi.org/api/timezone/Europe"

    request_params = {}

    if mytimer.past_due:
        logging.info('The timer is past due!')


    args = {
        "base_url": base_url,
        "request_params": request_params,
        "satellite_ids" : satellite_ids,
        "context" : context,
        "container_name" : STORAGE_CONTAINER_NAME,
    }

    ssl_context = ssl.create_default_context(cafile=certifi.where())
    async with aiohttp.TCPConnector(ssl=ssl_context) as connector:
        async with aiohttp.ClientSession(connector=connector) as session:
            await main(args, session)
    
    # ensure session is closed
    await asyncio.sleep(1)
    await session.close()
    await asyncio.sleep(1)
    await connector.close()
    logging.info(f"Entire function execution finished")
```

Now the problem is that, at least when I simulate locally in VSCode, the function gives an error (or warning actually because the debugging does not stop it) that the client session and connector are unclosed:

```bash
[2023-12-12T22:41:00.524Z] Unclosed client session
client_session: <aiohttp.client.ClientSession object at 0x000001E9A492CCD0>
[2023-12-12T22:41:00.526Z] Unclosed connector
connections: ['[(<aiohttp.client_proto.ResponseHandler object at 0x000001E9A48D7520>, 982955.203)]']
connector: <aiohttp.connector.TCPConnector object at 0x000001E9A492C7F0>
```

I did follow the [recommendation from aiohttp for graceful shotdown](https://docs.aiohttp.org/en/stable/client_advanced.html#graceful-shutdown), as well as the [recommendation to re-use the session](https://docs.aiohttp.org/en/stable/client_quickstart.html#make-a-request), but strangely at every function execution, I make 2 requests to the API, and I seem to get an error at every request. What can be the issue, and how can I resolve the error?

### EDIT 2024.01.15:

When I remove the `await` in this function:

```py
async def writeResponseToBlob(data, container_name, blob_name, connection_string):
       ...
        # Write the API response to the blob
        # await blob_client.upload_blob(data, overwrite=True)
        blob_client.upload_blob(data, overwrite=True)
```

then the problem disappears, and instead I get a warning:

```bash
...\function_app.py: RuntimeWarning: coroutine 'BlobClient.upload_blob' was never awaited
```

But how to make sure that this function works with both `await` on api call, and on blob upload?

Comment: For calling an API how you can get the api endpoint url? and are you able to get the response data in blob?

Comment: well I know the endpoint upfront of course. regarding writing to blob - yes this is succesfull. Overall the function performs correctly and executes succesfully, apart from this "unclosed session/connection" error.

Comment: `async with` closes the session (and connector), so those `.close()` methods are redundant. The `sys.exit()` call is a big red flag, I'd suggest removing that and finding a clean way to close the application (like raising an exception). Otherwise, adding the traceback would be useful (e.g. if you run `python -We` to turn warnings into errors, you'd get the trackback).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

turns out the problem was with the `writeResponseToBlob` method and what was missing was `async with` for the blob service client.

So this method now looks like this:

```py
async def writeResponseToBlob(data, connection_string, container_name, blob_name):
    logging.info(f'attempting to write to blob with container name: {container_name} and blob name: {blob_name} ...')
    try:
        async with BlobServiceClient.from_connection_string(connection_string) as blob_service_client:
            # Get a ContainerClient object for the specified container
            container_client = blob_service_client.get_container_client(container_name)
            # Write the API response to the blob
            blob_client = await container_client.upload_blob(name=blob_name, data=data, overwrite=True)
        return blob_client.blob_name
    except:
        logging.error("ERROR during blob upload : "+str(sys.exc_info()))
        return None
```

and that fixed the issues with the unclosed aiohttp session/connector.

Answer (score 1):

> I am writing an Azure Function App using Python (v2 programming model) that calls an API multiple times to get some data and write the responses to a blob storage.

You can use below code to do the same:

```
import azure.functions as func
import logging
import aiohttp
import asyncio
import ssl
import certifi
from azure.storage.blob import BlobServiceClient

app = func.FunctionApp(http_auth_level=func.AuthLevel.FUNCTION)
async def rith_fetch_data(url, rith_session):
    async with rith_session.get(url) as rith_response:
        return await rith_response.text()
@app.route(route="http_trigger")
async def http_trigger(req: func.HttpRequest) -> func.HttpResponse:
        rith_base_url = "https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com"
        endpoints = ["/posts/1", "/todos/1"]
        urls = [rith_base_url + endpoint for endpoint in endpoints]
        ssl_context = ssl.create_default_context(cafile=certifi.where())    
        connector = None
        async with aiohttp.TCPConnector(ssl=ssl_context) as connector:
            async with aiohttp.ClientSession(connector=connector) as rith_session:
            
                tasks = [rith_fetch_data(rith_url, rith_session) for rith_url in urls]
                responses = await asyncio.gather(*tasks)
 
                for rith_url, response in zip(urls, responses):
                    logging.info(f"Response from {rith_url}: {response}")
                rith_conn_string = "DefaultEndpointsProtocol=https;AccountName=rithwik;AccountKey=pPBW9jWuhgf+ASt5NLWkA==;EndpointSuffix=core.windows.net"
                rith_cont_name = "rithwik"
                rith_blob_name = "test.txt"
                rith_bsc = BlobServiceClient.from_connection_string(rith_conn_string)
                container_client = rith_bsc.get_container_client(rith_cont_name)
                rith_bc = container_client.get_blob_client(rith_blob_name)
                rith_bc.upload_blob("\n".join(responses))   
        await asyncio.sleep(1)
        await connector.close()
        logging.info("Hello Rithwik, Connector closed")

        return func.HttpResponse("Hello Rithwik Bojja, Data fetched and sent")
```

**`Output:`**

[image]

[image]

In Blob storage:

[image]

The above code worked for me without and errors or warnings.

Comment: thanks for looking into this. so the main difference i can see is that you are not closing the session but the connector, and i can see you are first declaring `connector = None`. I tried this approach but still getting the same error unfortunately...

Comment: I would suggest you to use my code and integrate your values into it as it works perfectly, then you can customize around it.

Comment: apologies i had to leave this for a month, now finally back to it. I did test your code locally, and it does work correctly. It covers though a slightly different scenario - in your scenario you get number of api responses, and you make a single write to a blob; the scenario I want to cover is when blob uploads happen every time after each response is returned. 
I am wondering also why you decided to not await blob_upload ? thnx for your comments